# Instapy not opening the browser

Tags: python, node.js, instagram, instapy

I'm a novice and started learning to use Instapy, bought a course which I'm considering asking a refund for, since the teacher won't answer. Before I do that, however, thought of giving it a chance and trying my luck here.

Here's the code:

```py
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

session = InstaPy(username='xxxxxxxxx', password='xxxxxxxxx')

with smart_run(session):
    session.set_do_follow(enabled = True, percentage = 100)
    session.set_do_like(enabled = True, percentage = 100)

session.like_by_tags(['João Pessoa', 'Joao Pessoa', 'Jampa'], amount=100)

comentarios = ['Legal', 'Cool']
session.set_do_comments(enabled=True, percentage=95)
session.set_comments(comentarios, media= 'Photo')
session.join_pods()
```

---

[code just like teacher's and cmd's commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSPRC.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts3KP.png)

https://youtu.be/f4Q11HbxazU - what happens, or better yet, does not happen...

Thank you very much for your help folks.

Answer (score 0):

Get a refund. (not legal advice)

In the first screenshot, an internet connection error inhibits the login process and in the second, it should be `set_do_comment` instead of `set_do_comments`.

See the (free) [docs](https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/blob/2a157d452611d37cf50ccb7d56ff1a06e9790ecb/docs/settings.md#commenting) for more information.